# Retrieving mysqli_real_escape_string from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

```
// inserting into DB from form

if (!empty($_POST['Title'])) {
    $t = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, ($_POST['Title']));
} else {
    $errors[] = 'Please enter a Headline title';
}

// Add the news to the database:

$q = 'INSERT INTO news ( Title, Content) VALUES (?, ?)';
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $q);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $t, $c);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

If the $t contains an apostrophe e.g

```
We're awesome
```

it will add it to the DB as

```
"we\'re awesome"
```

later on:

How do I then run a query where title = $t

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE title= '$t'";
```

The query fails because apostrophe cuts the SQL off effectively

```
SELECT * FROM news WHERE title = ' we're awesome
```

Comment: Are you sure in what you are talking? :) There's some missconceptions. You told us it's inserting `we\'re awesome` so the statement has to be `SELECT * FROM news WHERE title = 'we\'re awesome'`. Isn't it? P.S.: Why not: `$q = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE title = ?"`; `$stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $q); mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $row['title']); mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either escape or use prepared statements, but *not both*!

Comment: ah okay, so by using the prepared statement it already sanitises any user input? do you recommend removing the escape

Comment: Sure. Prepared statements are the state of the art and easy to use alternative to escaping. See also the Stack Overflow classic [How to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Answer (score 0):

You use mysqli_real_escape_string on your search again, like you did with the insert.

```
$t = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$t);
$q = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE title= '$t'";
```

That's it.